# Access value defined in a macro in another macro in ClojureScript

Tags: macros, clojurescript, resolve

Assume the following code

```
(defmacro sdef [sname]
  `(def ~sname 3))

(defmacro sinc [sname]
  (inc ... we want to access sname's value here...))
```

In ClojureScript we'd use it like this

```
(sdef sfoo)
(sinc sfoo) ; => 4
```

In our case it is mandatory that `sinc` is evaluated at compile time.

We managed to achieve this in Clojure using `resolve`, which didn't work in ClojureScript. We are aware, that especially in ClojureScript the macro evaluation is strictly separated from ClojureScript code execution.
However, is there a way to achieve the above?

Comment: Is the requirement that it all be done at compile time, without resorting to the following?

    (defmacro sinc [sname]
     `(inc ~sname))

Comment: You will have to add more context about why you are seeking such a bizarre thing.  You could always do a pre-processing step on your code if you really had to.

Comment: Yes, it has to be done at compile time. We are defining our own data-structures and binding structural information in a def (cf. sdef).  These data-structures' shape is then compile time checked, when used in another macro (cf. sinc). To do so, we need the structural information bound earlier. This works quite well in Clojure, however, we want it to work with ClojureScript, too.

Comment: Independent of whether you find a solution, it seems you'd want to add const meta to the def produced by sdef. (The semantics especially line up for this in ClojureScript.) I say this because, by default, Vars don't have compile-time linkage to their values.